# How can I create a shortcut for a command in Mathematica?

Tags: keyboard

I am using mathematica to write my physics homework, one thing that trouble me is that I need to enter lots of vectors. I usually type the name of the vector, "A" for example, and then hit "[Ctrl]  7" and "[Esc] vec [Esc]" to get a full vector representation. May I create a shortcut, like "[Alt] v" for example, to automatically finish this process?

Comment: Duplicate:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4209405/customizing-mathematica-shortcuts

Comment: @DavidG.Stork Thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It seem to me that for a task like writing homework, it would be complete overkill to try anything fancy or low-level. So I would suggest instead to go with something like this, which just applies in the current notebook and also just for the particular vector you use most commonly:

```
SetOptions[EvaluationNotebook[], 
 InputAutoReplacements -> {"aa" -> ToBoxes[
\!\(\*OverscriptBox[\(a\), \(\[RightVector]\)]\)]}]
```

Now if you type `aa` followed by a space, it will immediately change to $\vec{a}$.

Also be aware that you should use such constructs primarily for typesetting. Don't try using things like $\vec{a}$ in the same way you would use variables, unless you know what you're doing. See [this tutorial](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/18393/245) and search for issues related to subscripted symbols. The same warnings apply to vectors.

**Edit: general vectors**

The above is the fastest method to input specific vectors. In practice, all you have to do is type the symbol you want to create, and paste it in the `ToBoxes` that wraps $\vec{a}$ in the above example. To add more individual characters, just add the analogous definitions, such as `"bb" -> ToBoxes[...]`, to the list `{...}`.

To do something similar for *arbitrary* vectors, you will need more keystrokes. First enter

```
SetOptions[EvaluationNotebook[], 
  InputAutoReplacements -> 
  {"vv" -> OverscriptBox["\[NegativeMediumSpace]\[SelectionPlaceholder]", 
     "\[RightVector]"]}]
```

Now you can type `vv` followed by a space to get a placeholder into which you type the desired letter(s). Then you can press the arrow navigation keys or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>.</kbd> repeatedly to get out of the placeholder when done.

The above use of [`InputAutoReplacements`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/InputAutoReplacements.html) adds a space under the vector symbol, which I then have to undo by adding `\[NegativeMediumSpace]`. To avoid this, you could also do this:

```
SetOptions[EvaluationNotebook[], 
 InputAliases -> {"vv" -> 
    OverscriptBox["\[SelectionPlaceholder]", "\[RightVector]"]}]
```

With this method, you would have to type <kbd>Esc</kbd>`vv`<kbd>Esc</kbd> to get the vector template, so it takes one additional keystroke. But it doesn't require me to add the `\[NegativeMediumSpace]` in the output.

Comment: How to generalize this method to any vectors?

Comment: Maybe the edited answer will help.

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution is to use a global phrase replacement application like Phrase Express, which you can limit specific phrase 'shortcuts' to a specific application, like Mathematica.  I store many shortcuts in Phrase Express for Mathematica, which helps speed up my input dramatically, and I don't need to worry about using packages or default notebooks to do the same thing.

Phrase Express is a closed source application, which offers a free version with limited functionality, and a paid version for more advanced functionality.

Comment: You might want to mention that [PhraseExpress](http://www.phraseexpress.com/docs11/09/shop.php) is a third-party, closed-source application which costs upwards of 50 USD. Looks like a nice tool though.

Comment: Thanks Dionys, I did add a comment, but want to note that they do offer a free limited version of their software which is actually pretty complete.  You might want to check it out.